# Deploying a scheduler cloud function (function Failed to create function "function_name"--- HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to deploy a scheduled cloud function and while deploying i am getting the error as :-

> HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors
>
> Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
>
> ```
> scheduledFunction
> ```
>
> To try redeploying those functions, run:
>
> ```
> firebase deploy --only functions:scheduledFunction
> ```
>
> To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
>
> ```
> firebase deploy --except functions
> ```
>
> Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.schedulefunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun(async context => {console.log('running every 5 minutes');});
```

Comment: If you have unexpected problems with deployment, you should contact Firebase support directly with the contents of your error logs.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: updating firebase-tools, firebase-functions solved my problem:  npm install -g firebase-tools@latest , npm install -g firebase-functions@latest